# フォルダ内の全てのファイルに対して処理を実行させたい

Tags: macos, bash

フォルダ内の全てのPCAPファイルをtsharkに処理させたいと思います。

フォルダ(/log)の中に、A.pcapng , B.pcapng というファイルがあります。

```
#!/bin/sh
for filepath in /log 
do
tshark -r $1 -Y "wlan.fcs_bad == 0 && wlan.ta == 00:00:00:00:00:00" fields -E separator’;’ -e frame.time_relative  -e wlan.seq —e tcp.seq -e radiotap.datarate -e radiotap.mcs.index -e radiotap.channel.type > $1-ta.csv
tshark -r $1  -Y "wlan.fcs_bad == 0 && wlan.ra == 00:00:00:00:00:00" fields -E separator’;’ -e frame.time_relative  -e wlan.seq -e tcp.seq -e radiotap.datarate -e radiotap.mcs.index -e radiotap.channel.type > $1-ra.csv
done
read wait
```

$1にA.pcapng , B.pcapng が自動的に入るようにしたいのですが、どう引数を渡せばいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

for filepath in /log/*.pcapng
do
  tshark -r $filepath -Y "wlan.fcs_bad == 0 && wlan.ta == 00:00:00:00:00:00" fields -E separator’;’ -e frame.time_relative  -e wlan.seq —e tcp.seq -e radiotap.datarate -e radiotap.mcs.index -e radiotap.channel.type > ${filepath}-ta.csv
  tshark -r $filepath -Y fields "wlan.fcs_bad == 0 && wlan.ra == 00:00:00:00:00:00" -E separator’;’ -e frame.time_relative  -e wlan.seq -e tcp.seq -e radiotap.datarate -e radiotap.mcs.index -e radiotap.channel.type > ${filepath}-ra.csv
done
read wait
```

`for filepath in ...`としていますので`$filepath`で参照できます。
また、このままですと、出力先は`A.pcapng-ta.csv`といったファイル名になります。
出力先を`${filepath%.*}-ta.csv`にすれば`A-ta.csv`になりよりスマートです。

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/bin/sh
for file in `\find . -name '*.pcapng'`; do

tshark -r $file -Y "wlan.fcs_bad == 0 && wlan.ta == 00:00:00:00:00:00"  -T fields -E separator’,’ -e frame.time_relative  -e wlan.seq —e tcp.seq -e radiotap.datarate -e radiotap.mcs.index -e radiotap.channel.type > $file-1.csv
tshark -r $file -Y "wlan.fcs_bad == 0 && wlan.ra == 00:00:00:00:00:00" -T fields -E separator’,’ -e frame.time_relative  -e wlan.seq -e tcp.seq -e radiotap.datarate -e radiotap.mcs.index -e radiotap.channel.type > $file-2.csv
done
read wait
```

findコマンドを使ってみました。

Comment: ちなみにこの方法の場合、スペースを含むファイル名などがあるとエラーになります。

Answer (score 0):

フォルダ(/log)の中に、A.pcapng , B.pcapng だけなら、

```
for f in `ls /log`
do
    echo ${f};    //${f}を使った処理
done
```

のように、`ls`でもできます。

Comment: ちなみにこの方法の場合、スペースを含むファイル名などがあるとエラーになります。